Deploying selenium/flask/docker script in Python
I'm having some issues deploying a selenium scraping script in render. Locally the script runs fine, when I deploy it on render and I try to access the endpoint to trigger the script this is the problem it shows:

WebDriverException
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/125.0.6422.60/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

The script structure is the following:

I'm  going ahead and making a copy of the script, if something is unclear please let me know:
wiki_script.py :
# BeautifulSoup imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Selenium imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Flask imports
from flask import Flask, request


'''0. We create the flask app'''
app = Flask(__name__)


'''1. Main function'''
def main_script():

    # Url to scrape
    url = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/'

    # Selenium parameters, headless for deploy

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.6045.160 Safari/537.36")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    # Opens the url
    driver.get(url)

    # Parse the url with beautifulsoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")

    # Find the class that has the english text
    lang_elements = soup.find_all(class_='central-featured-lang lang2')

    # Get the 'English' text and print it from inside 'strong' attribute
    strong_texts = []

    for element in lang_elements:
        strong_tag = element.find('strong')
        if strong_tag:
            strong_texts.append(strong_tag.get_text())

    print(strong_texts)
    return strong_texts
    

'''2. Configs for the API and Flask'''

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])

def home():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):

        return main_script()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

requirements.txt :
beautifulsoup4
selenium
Flask
webdriver-manager
packaging
gunicorn

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV PORT=5000
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["python", "wiki_script.py"]

I've tried a couple of changes in how I set up the Chrome options, but nothing seems to work really fine and I'm a little lost, any help would be appreciated.

I was running into the exact same issue with a similar program after switching from webdriver-manager to the native Selenium webdriver manager. You seem to be doing the same, although your requirements.txt contains webdriver-manager, you do not appear to be using it. Most older answers on this site to similar questions are shown using webdriver-manager, but I wanted to solve without that.
After viewing many similar issues on Stackoverflow I found the solution was to install chromium-driver in my Dockerfile, as this would install other dependencies that Selenium's chromedriver requires. It's likely that my own laptop environment contains these libs as dependencies for other programs, while my remote server does not.
tl;dr I added the following line to my Dockerfile:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium-driver 
Here's the essence of my own program, though I do use other options:
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()


I was able to deploy on render without any problems using the following code.
wiki_script.py :
# BeautifulSoup imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Selenium imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



# Flask imports
from flask import Flask, request


'''0. We create the flask app'''
app = Flask(__name__)


'''1. Main function'''
def main_script():

    # Url to scrape
    url = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/'

    # Selenium parameters, headless for deploy

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

    # Opens the url
    driver.get(url)

    # Parse the url with beautifulsoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")

    # Find the class that has the english text
    lang_elements = soup.find_all(class_='central-featured-lang lang2')

    # Get the 'English' text and print it from inside 'strong' attribute
    strong_texts = []

    for element in lang_elements:
        strong_tag = element.find('strong')
        if strong_tag:
            strong_texts.append(strong_tag.get_text())

    print(strong_texts)
    return strong_texts
    

'''2. Configs for the API and Flask'''

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])

def home():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):

        return main_script()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

requirements.txt :
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
selenium==4.9.1
Flask
webdriver-manager==4.0.0
packaging
gunicorn

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.install.org -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean

CMD ["python", "wiki_script.py"]

The main changes were made in the Dockerfile, which allowed Chrome to be installed successfully. I forced the version for some libraries as seen in requirements.txt.
